# php5-curl, php5-common and PHP 5.6.3-1~dotdeb.1 on Debian Wheezy

Tags: curl, debian, php-5.6

I'm using **Debian 7 Wheezy** with Nginx and **PHP 5.6.3-1~dotdeb.1**. When trying to install **php5-curl** apt-get tells me that it requires `php5-common (= 5.4.35-0+deb7u2) but 5.6.3-1~dotdeb.1 ...` and installation fails. When I try to install php5-common my apt-get tells me that it is installed in its newest version.

I'm getting above error on my development PC. Strange, but on production VPS server with the same configuration (exactly the same Debian, Nginx, PHP 5.6.3-1~dotdeb.1) installation was succesful.

Any ideas how to install php5-curl on my PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

There was somothing wrong with apt-get tool. While running `sudo apt-get update` I got some errors about improper headers etc. After running a bunch of commands:

`sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update`

these errors disappeared and I was able to succesfull install php5-curl.